# Simple SMPP Perl Script

Tags: perl, tcp, binding

I need your help/advices on my very short script I wrote in Perl in order to send SMS via SMPP protocol.

I got a SMS gateway which is perfectly working (sending SMS via HTML request or via web interface works), let's say this gateway has IP 192.168.1.15.
Its SMPP service is listening to TCP 2775 (I can successfully telnet to 2775, so I guess SMPP service is working on my SMS gateway)

```
my $smpp = Net::SMPP->new_transmitter(192.168.1.15,
                                       port=>2775,
                                       system_id =>"administrator",
                                       password =>"passwdexample") or die;

$resp_pdu = $smpp->submit_sm(destination_addr => '+400123456789',
                              short_message => 'test message') or die;

die "Response indicated error: " . $Resp_PDU->explain_status() if $resp_pdu->status;
```

When I run the script, here the error I got :

> Response indicated error: Incorrect BIND Status for given command (ESME_RINVBNDS TS=0x00000004) at C:\temp\smpptest.pl line .

Unfortunately, I haven't find so much help on internet, but according to this link : [SMPP Errors Codes](https://www.openmarket.com/customer-center/documentation/SMSSMPP_APIGuide/index.htm#76998.htm) It says :

> You must bind first before any other request is handled.

However, my bind is done with new_transmitter, and I don't get any errors at this point, so I don't understand how it cannot bind the TCP session (my credentials are corrects, I tried that in a telnet session).

That's the first time I use such a plugin, so maybe I'm missing something, and maybe someone has already met this error !

Many thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to quote the IP address:

```
Net::SMPP->new_transmitter("192.168.1.15", ...);
```

Comment: Absolutely. Well spotted

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :-) Unfortunately, I have tried with quotes, also by using a variable, but I get the exact same error message. Do you think it has something to do with the SMSC itself ?